# CSS: Position on Resizing?

Tags: html, css

Whatever I try, float, or absolute position, at resizing it fails and change position.

I tried a normal menu and div elements, but if i resize at my browser it changes position.

What I want when you resize is that it keeps the position nomatter what so you have to scroll to the left to see the floated element/positioned element.

E.g stackoverflow.com or facebook, if you resize and try to move the browser sides, you see that nothing is moving, and the scroll gets longer the smaller the browser gets..

Check here:
http://jsbin.com/ezaco4
then resize it and try to moving your browsers right side around and you will see that it moves.

It may be a nature html, but how can I then get what I want to do, so it keeps the position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a fixed width container. Your example is in the `body` so it will resize to the width of the container, in this case the body.

```
<body>
    <div style="width: 700px;">
        <ul style="float: right;">
            <li>item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```